# Change an array value if duplicate

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which holds some articles of a website. The problem is: when the same article is in 2 different categories it only shows 1. In this example the categories are 'Service' and 'Sales'.

If the article is duplicate and the category is 'Sales' I want 1 of them to change to 'Service' and vice versa.

The array I got now(3 & 4 as duplicates and 7 & 8):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sales
            [1] => assistentiesystemen
            [2] => www.youtube.com/video/38BbjLmVJXk
            [3] => Park assist
        )


[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sales
        [1] => assistentiesystemen
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/3lGfTZdVK1s
        [3] => Multi Collision braking system
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sales
        [1] => assistentiesystemen
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/6mgDraWpGvE
        [3] => Area view
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sales
        [1] => assistentiesystemen
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/II68oVm4zro
        [3] => Lane Assist
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sales
        [1] => assistentiesystemen
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/II68oVm4zro
        [3] => Lane Assist
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sales
        [1] => assistentiesystemen
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/N0fa4dUBkvE
        [3] => Trailer assist
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => Service
        [1] => veilig-op-de-weg
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/NCNDyW6Yr1g
        [3] => Ruitenwissers
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => Service
        [1] => veilig-op-de-weg
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/PJEC-yqUwzE
        [3] => Bandenafdichtset
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => Service
        [1] => veilig-op-de-weg
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/PJEC-yqUwzE
        [3] => Bandenafdichtset
    )

)
```

The array I want to accomplish (No duplicates anymore and the values changed):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sales
            [1] => assistentiesystemen
            [2] => www.youtube.com/video/38BbjLmVJXk
            [3] => Park assist
        )


[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sales
        [1] => assistentiesystemen
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/3lGfTZdVK1s
        [3] => Multi Collision braking system
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sales
        [1] => assistentiesystemen
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/6mgDraWpGvE
        [3] => Area view
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Service
        [1] => assistentiesystemen
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/II68oVm4zro
        [3] => Lane Assist
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sales
        [1] => assistentiesystemen
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/II68oVm4zro
        [3] => Lane Assist
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sales
        [1] => assistentiesystemen
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/N0fa4dUBkvE
        [3] => Trailer assist
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => Service
        [1] => veilig-op-de-weg
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/NCNDyW6Yr1g
        [3] => Ruitenwissers
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sales
        [1] => veilig-op-de-weg
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/PJEC-yqUwzE
        [3] => Bandenafdichtset
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => Service
        [1] => veilig-op-de-weg
        [2] => www.youtube.com/video/PJEC-yqUwzE
        [3] => Bandenafdichtset
    )

)
```

What I tried:

```
$length = count ($sorted);

    for ($c = 0; $c < $length; $c++) {
        $check_array = $sorted[$c];

        for ($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
            $compare_array = $sorted[$x];

            if ($x != $i){

                if($check_array[2] == $compare_array[2] && $check_array[0] == $compare_array[0]){
                    //print_r ($check_array);
                    //print_r ($compare_array);
                    if($check_array[0] == 'Sales'){
                        $compare_array[0] = 'Service';
                    }
                    if($check_array[0] == 'Service'){
                        $compare_array[0] = 'Sales';
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What are those few things ?? can you show ew things you did

Comment: Added my code which doesn't work

Comment: you are trying to change the sales to service and service to sales

Comment: Thats right, only if the youtube url and the category are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your data in `$array` variable and try it:

```
$hash = array_map( function ( $value ) { return md5( implode( $value ) ); } , $array);

$keys = array_keys( array_diff_assoc( $hash, array_unique( $hash ) ) );

foreach( $keys as $key )
    $array[ $key ][0] = $array[ $key ][0] == 'Service' ? 'Sales' : 'Service';
```

Comment: nice approach. but I think you can just use `$hash = array_map('serialize', $array);` for "hashing".

Comment: Only the sales duplicates are handled right, it doesnt seem to work on the service duplicates. Any ideas?

Comment: 7 & 8 is service duplicates. it's right! order is important for you?

Comment: 7 & 8 are indeed service duplicates. They both still are after running them code. While 1 of the needs to be sales.

Comment: It works on my array example above, but when I implement it for my real array with 113 elements the service ones don't work. Any idea?

Comment: Can you give me your 113 elements?

Comment: This is the array after running the code: http://pastebin.com/dnNaAGcV for example element 75 & 113 are duplicates

Comment: I test it and get correct output! where is wrong in array? specify array index to check [0-113].

Comment: Hmm weird, this is the output: http://pastebin.com/Bx2cdyJM all the elements from 0 - 53 are fine but from 54 - 113 isnt changing anything. So converting sale to service is working perfect, but from service to sales not. Do you maybe have an idea why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138807/discussion-between-mahdiy-and-remco-a).

Answer (score 1):

If the order is not important for you, you can use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
$replacements = [
    'Sales' => 'Service',
    'Service' => 'Sales'
];

// Sort array by youtube url.
array_multisort($array, array_column($array, 2));

array_walk($array, function (&$curr, $_, &$prev) use ($replacements) {
    if (
        $prev !== null
        && $prev[2] === $curr[2]
    ) {
        $curr[0] = $replacements[$curr[0]];
    }

    $prev = $curr;
}, null);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/087361af7452d57dd9529a746a44b2101116b903).

Comment: Works, thanks! I think MahdiY's answer is the best solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a written some code, you can try it.

```
<?php    
$array = [
    [
        0 => 'Sales',
        1 => 'assistentiesystemen',
        2 => 'www.youtube.com/video/38BbjLmVJXk',
        3 => 'Park assist',
    ],
    [
        0 => 'Sales',
        1 => 'assistentiesystemen',
        2 => 'www.youtube.com/video/3lGfTZdVK1s',
        3 => 'Multi Collision braking system'
    ],
    [
        0 => 'Sales',
        1 => 'assistentiesystemen',
        2 => 'www.youtube.com/video/6mgDraWpGvE',
        3 => 'Area view'
    ],
    [
        0 => 'Sales',
        1 => 'assistentiesystemen',
        2 => 'www.youtube.com/video/II68oVm4zro',
        3 => 'Lane Assist'
    ],
    [
        0 => 'Sales',
        1 => 'assistentiesystemen',
        2 => 'www.youtube.com/video/II68oVm4zro',
        3 => 'Lane Assist'
    ],
    [
        0 => 'Sales',
        1 => 'assistentiesystemen',
        2 => 'www.youtube.com/video/N0fa4dUBkvE',
        3 => 'Trailer assist'
    ],
    [
        0 => 'Service',
        1 => 'veilig-op-de-weg',
        2 => 'www.youtube.com/video/NCNDyW6Yr1g',
        3 => 'Ruitenwissers'
    ],
    [
        0 => 'Service',
        1 => 'veilig-op-de-weg',
        2 => 'www.youtube.com/video/PJEC-yqUwzE',
        3 => 'Bandenafdichtset'
    ],
    [
        0 => 'Service',
        1 => 'veilig-op-de-weg',
        2 => 'www.youtube.com/video/PJEC-yqUwzE',
        3 => 'Bandenafdichtset'
    ]
];

/**
 * @param $firstIndexValue
 * @param $thirdIndexValue
 * @param $searchArray
 * @return bool
 */
function isExistValue($firstIndexValue, $thirdIndexValue, $searchArray)
{
    foreach ($searchArray as $element) {
        if ($firstIndexValue == $element[0] && $thirdIndexValue == $element[3]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}


$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    $isExist = isExistValue($arr[0], $arr[3], $newArray);
    if ($isExist) {
        if ($arr[0] == 'Sales') {
            $arr[0] = 'Service';
        } elseif ($arr[0] == 'Service') {
            $arr[0] = 'Sales';
        }
    }
    $newArray[] = $arr;
}

var_dump($newArray);
```